# Error installing Google App Engine Plugin Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to install Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse .

I downloaded Eclipse Java EE version or Eclipse jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64 ,  == 64 bit for my pc.When i  search in Eclipse market place there is no search found for Google Plugin for Eclipse at all.I went 2 this site = https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started , but there is no version in there of mine ,even if i go to older versions ,there is no version of mine there.I am using Indigo n they have links for Juno, mars ,etc etc.
IF i try the link of eclipse 4.5 latest version , it doesn't work= https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.5
How do i install it on my Eclipse Indigo Latest version ?

Comment: Indigo is 5 years old, with no support for later versions of Java (7? , 8) why not install a later version? Too many plugins installed to bother ?

Comment: The last (for the moment) is Mars http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/marsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE Indigo has some bugs in it ,

Better upgrade to Mars 4.5 Java EE Eclipse